# VueJS 3 composition API randomly updating reactive variable

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have in my `setup` function this reactive variable:

```
const publication = reactive({
  title: '',
  illustration: {
    type: '',
    val: '',
  },
  id: '',
});
```

I can update the `illustration.val` with 2 functions:

```
function selectBiblio(e) {
  publication.illustration.val = e.id;
}
```

or

```
watch(otherIllustration, (n, o) => {
  if (n && n[0] && n[0].id) {
    publication.illustration.val = n[0].id;
    console.log(`OK: ${publication.illustration.val}`);
  } else {
    publication.illustration.val = '';
  }
});
```

The first one is a click on a button and the new `publication.illustration.val` is immediately taken into account.
The second watches anoher ref (`const otherIllustration = ref([]);`) to change and should also update `publication.illustration.val` immediately when the new `otherIllustration` is loaded, but it doesn't, although the `log` (the line with "`OK`") shows that the variable assignment is OK.

I really don't understand, because when I change `otherIllustration` AGAIN, `publication.illustration.val`gets the previous value. It seems to always be one assignment late... If I change `publication.title`, it updates to the correct value. Very strange!

Another thing very strange: if I assign `'0'` instead of `''`, it works perfectly.

Could anybody explain me what happens here?
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Works fine. Are you sure you don't have any typo?

Comment: I'm 100% sure, it's a copy/paste :)

Comment: Please then, make a reproduction on codepen or codesandbox. I will take a look.

Comment: I tried but I can't... codesandbox always gives an error (`Parsing error: Unexpected token`) although my code is right...

Comment: here, try using mine: https://codepen.io/Adam_Orlov/pen/LYbNLJg?editors=1010

Comment: OK I checked your codepen example, it works. The fact is that in my app the "otherIllustration" is linked to a child component, it seems the problem is with this one. I'll make further investigationandcomeback here after that. Thanks for your codepen!